Win32 - Wait for arrival/receive notification of new HID Feature Report
I’m currently working on an application that configures RGB lighting for a USB keyboard. The keyboard adheres to the HID (Human Interface Device) specification, allowing customization through HID feature reports. However, I’ve encountered an unexpected behaviour.
My understanding of the HID specification is that HID feature reports have specific report IDs for each configurable option, with HidD_GetFeature being used to retrieve the current state of each option, and HidD_SetFeature being used to modify it. However, this particular keyboard has only one report ID and a single feature report structure for bidirectional communication. For instance, to obtain the firmware version, I must construct a feature report struct with the appropriate query, and the device responds with a feature report containing the firmware version.
It would seem to me like the Windows HID APIs haven't really been designed to accommodate this style of bidirectional communication through feature reports, in that there doesn't seem to be any way for me to wait for, or be notified of, the arrival of a new feature report. This means I'm having to call HidD_SetFeature, sleep for an arbitrary duration, and then call HidD_GetFeature. This approach means there is always the potential of receiving stale or incorrect data.
My question is: Is there a more effective way to handle bidirectional communication with feature reports? Specifically, is there a way to be notified of the arrival of a new feature report or to wait for one to arrive without relying on Sleep?

You can register for device input using RegisterRawInputDevices
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices and then get hid data from WM_INPUT message, RAWINPUT struct etc

There is no way to be notified about feature reports according to the HID spec:

Note. Only Input reports are sent via the Interrupt In pipe. Feature and Output reports must be initiated by the host via the Control pipe or an optional Interrupt Out pipe.

Input reports could be read from device interface using ReadFile API. Alternatively you can process RawInput API WM_INPUT message - it will contain same input reports.
Please note that you cannot read input data from the HID keyboard directly in Windows - due to security reasons.
See HID spec and Obtaining HID Reports by user-mode applications for more info.
